# how to redirect a url that does not contain specific text using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site that has a some pdf files to download. i want to block direct file download.
example: if a user try https://skpselearning.enovic.in/uploads/document/viewer.html?file=lesson9.pdf it should download. but without viewer.html? it will should be block. ie https://skpselearning.enovic.in/uploads/document/lesson9.pdf this url will be block. how to do this?

Comment: One easy solution is to put the pdfs in a directory *that you don't give web access to*. E.g. put them in `mysecretfolder`, then have viewer.html return file at `.../mysecretfolder/lesson9.pdf`.

Comment: "`/viewer.html?file=lesson9.pdf `" - Exactly _how_ is your script managing the download? What technology are you using? The use of `viewer.html` makes it "look-like" you are using client-side JavaScript. But if you are using JS then the files need to be directly accessible (perhaps "hobbled" by an additional HTTP request header - but this is relatively trivial to bypass). This download script needs to be server-side.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of doing this? Is this for "security"? Or do you simply want to route `.pdf` requests through your script, which you could do without preventing so-called "direct" access and without having to use a URL that exposes your `viewer.html` script.

Comment: i want to stop direct access to the file. they download via site only. like hotlink protection. i want to stop users simply copy paste the url and download the pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

(You've not stated how your `viewer.html` script is downloading/displaying the `.pdf` files? Simply blocking direct access to the `.pdf` files could also block access to your script, depending how it is implemented.)

So, all you are really asking (and all that can be answered) is how to block direct access to the `.pdf` files...

To block (403 Forbidden) HTTP access to all `.pdf` files on the site:

```
<Files "*.pdf">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Or, to block only `.pdf` files in the `/uploads/document` subdirectory then you can use the following mod_rewrite directives at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^uploads/document/[^/]+\.pdf$ - [F]
```